# Is it possible to set a badge number from push notification in Android without starting an app

Tags: android, push-notification, badge, android-push-notification

I want to send a push notification to my Android app with a number for a badge. I know how to set badge number from within the app. But is it possible to send such a push message, which will update a badge number to the one specified in the message?

It is possible on iOS: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/PayloadKeyReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH17-SW1.

How about Android?